# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'media' of undefined On using Instagram API

Tags: instagram, media

I'm trying to scrape data of a specific Instagram user by using the Instagram API. When I try to get the photos, it throws an error as:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'media' of undefined On
>   using Instagram API".

Can anyone can suggest me a solution?

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

            var username = "leomessi";
            var max_num_items = 15;

            var jqxhr = $.ajax("https://www.instagram.com/" + username + "/?__a=1&").done(function () {
                //alert( "success" );
            }).fail(function () {
                //alert( "error" );
            }).always(function (data) {
                //alert( "complete" )
                debugger;
                items = data.user.media.nodes;
                $.each(items, function (n, item) {
                    if ((n + 1) <= max_num_items) {
                        var data_li = "<li><a target='_blank' href='https://www.instagram.com/p/" + item.code + "'><img src='" + item.thumbnail_src + "'/></a></li>";
                        $("ul.instagram").append(data_li);
                    }
                });

            });

        });
```

```css
 ul.instagram {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.instagram li {
  float: left;
}

ul.instagram li img {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="instagram">
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you checked the log for an error message?

Comment: yes i did,i get log saying:                                                                Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
insta.html:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'media' of undefined

Comment: is it because my access to site is blocked in my machine ?

Comment: Your request URL doesn't look correct.

Comment: i modified my request as "https://www.instagram.com/beingsalmankhan/?__a=1", but still getting the same error

Comment: That still doesn't look like a valid Instagram API request: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent